# ORDER BY CASE & Ordinal not working

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Sorting column #7 as an example -

This code does not sort data at all:

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN '1'='2' THEN 5 
 WHEN '1'='1' THEN 7 
 ELSE 13 END
```

[image: Sort ignored...]

If I change it to a hard-coded ordinal it works:

```
ORDER BY 7
```

[image]

Comment: '1' = '2' etc were used for purpose of demonstrating the issue. They are actually real true/false expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the respective expressions in the `SELECT` list are of the same type, you can do it by using the expressions themselves instead of the `SELECT` list number:

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ...
...
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN 1=2
            THEN expression5
            WHEN 1=1
            THEN expression7
            ELSE expression13
         END;
```

If the data types are not the same, season with type casts.

Your query does not work because only integer literals can be used as column numbers in `ORDER BY`. In all other cases, an integer just stands for its constant value.

If it were not like this, `ORDER BY` expressions could easily become ambiguous. Look at the following:

```
... ORDER BY intcol + 3;
```

Should that mean “add three” or “add expression number three from the `SELECT` list”?

Comment: So a case & ordinal combination is not actually possible? I can indeed get it working using the full column expressions.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley: correct. [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) "*Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item), **or** it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column values*"

Comment: It is not possible, yes. I have added an explanation to the answer.